# How to get the pictures from a folder one by one and display them on a page with specific text for each image using php?

Tags: php, image, text

I use this code to add products on my webpage...

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
<tr>
<td width="250" >  <a href="img/01.JPG" rel="lightbox" ><img src="img/01a.JPG" border="0"   width="200" height="150"><br><br><br><br></a>   </td>
<td width="250" >
<center>
<span class="style2">Name of the product</span><br>
Description of the product
<br><br>
<b></b><br><br><br><br><br>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I don't want to rewrite this code over and over again... I want a code that will get the images of the products from a folder and display them with a specific text for each product.

The texts for all product will bee in a folder with the same number as the image(image number 01, text number 01, image number 02, text number 02 etc. ).

If a product doesn't have a text file it will be displayed(the image of the product) but without text.

In the folder of images I have the image and the thumbnail image of the same product(01.jpg-image, 01a.jpg-thumbnail image, 02.jpg-image, 02a.jpg-thumbnail image etc. ).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `$filepath` and try it with this piece of code :

```
<?
$string =array();
$filePath='directorypath/';  
$dir = opendir($filePath);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
   if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) ) { 
   $string[] = $file;
   }
}
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
  $img = array_pop($string);
  echo "<img src='$filePath$img'  width='100px'/>";
}
?>
```

Also have a look at the **Official PHP Site**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

### To make it Dynamic follow the below listed steps

**Step 1 :** Create a table named images

```
create table `images` (
`id` int(4)auto_increment,
`imagename` varchar(30),
`description` varchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**Step 2 :** Create the connection file `conf.php`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

**Step 3 :** Create the `image.php` file

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$sql="select image, description from images";
$sql_res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>
<img src="folderpath/<?php echo $row["images"];?> />
Description 
<?php
echo $row['description'];
?>
```

**Once done, put the connection file (config.php), images.php and the images folder in the same directory and run the images.php once giving the appropriate values to directorypath, database name, username, password etc.**

**Once done, your goal will be achieved.**

Comment: But the text... the description of the product.

Comment: If so connecting with database is the best.

Comment: I don't know hot to work with databases... I've learned html in school and some php at home but not very nuch... I am at the beginning... thanks for the PHP Manual :)

Comment: By the way... can you give me a complete tutorial for php(all of php)... at home I've learned form an old book that my brother give'd  me from 2005 of Steven Holzner.